# Binding data to a hyperlink repeater - how can I control the Text attribute value of each hyperlink?

Tags: asp.net, .net, repeater

I have a hyperlink repeater that I bind with a `List<string>` containing some URLs:

```
<asp:Repeater id="linksRepeater" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>       
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='Url to ??' NavigateUrl='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

// Bind data in the code behind
List<string> urls = GetUrls();
linksRepeater.DataSource = urls;
linksRepeater.DataBind();

// Example:
// urls[0] = "http://siteA.com/subsite/sub/sub2/web1.html" 
// urls[1] = "http://siteA.com/subsite/x/y/web2.html"
// urls[2] = "http://siteB.com/x/web3.html"
```

The problem is, using this code, all hyperlinks are of course displayed like this:

- "Url to ??"
- "Url to ??"
- "Url to ??"

Instead, I would like to replace the`Text` attribute of each hyperlink instance with a result of the following method call:
`string TransformUrl(string url)` - like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='Url to <%# TransformUrl(Container.DataItem.ToString()) %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>' />
```

However, this code results in an error. The `TransformURL()` method processes the URL and returns a new string, i.e. I'm trying to get something like:

- "Url to siteA.com web1 [status: ok]"
- "Url to siteA.com web2 [status: ok]"
- "Url to siteB.com web3 [status: missing]"

What's the best way to do this, i.e. assign a different text attribute for each hyperlink based on the value of `Container.DataItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. The only thing to change is how your are literal string with computed value - it is better to do it inside the `<%# %>` tag:

```
Text='<%# string.Format("Url to {0}", TransformUrl(Container.DataItem.ToString())) %>'
```

Comment: In addition to this, I had to make another change to get it working. My `<asp:Repeater>` is inside UserControl.ascx, while the method was inside UserControl.ascx.cs - I had to move the method from .cs to .ascx as a script:

`<script runat="server" type="text/C#">string TransformUrl(...){...}</script>`

Comment: @w128, actually this is something you can fix a better way, I think. How was it declared? If just `string TransformUrl`, then it was private by default and not visible from markup. You can declare it as protected in code behind class and keep markup clean